# CSS Grid: wrap & fit to content

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, flexboxgrid

I want to wrap my list and at the same time make it fit to the content like this:

[image]

The problem is that each element must fit the width of its content.

I've already found [example](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/) how to wrap items of fixed size but it doesn't help me in my case:
`grid-template-columns: repeat( 12, minmax(250px, 1fr) );`

I tried several combinations but without success, the list is either fixed in one row, or the elements overlap each other. Also I can't find any good example for this case.

```html
<style>
.container {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 30px) );
}
.item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">First item</div>
  <div class="item">Second item</div>
  <div class="item">Some text here</div>
  <div class="item">Example</div>
  <div class="item">Wrapped item</div>
  <div class="item">Another wrapped item</div>
</div>
```

This is what I get for now:

[image]

Comment: A grid is a series of tracks arranged in columns and rows. The columns are **one width** from top to bottom. In other words, a "fixed width." A column can't have different widths on different rows because then you don't have a grid (like in your first image). Flexbox may be a better solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grid produces rows and columns, like a spreadsheet. The layout you're after is best achieved using a flexbox.

```css
.container {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}
.item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">First item</div>
  <div class="item">Second item</div>
  <div class="item">Some text here</div>
  <div class="item">Example</div>
  <div class="item">Wrapped item</div>
  <div class="item">Another wrapped item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this example! I forgot that flexbox supports `gap` property too (there was a time when there was no support). I hope that no one needs to use such wrapping behavior in conjunction with the grid otherwise someone will have to wrestle with the solution.

Comment: You can nest a flexbox inside a grid if you need to.